# Calculating fixed effects in a mixed model with non-normality and heteroscedasticity with a 3-level time variable?

Tags: mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption, ancova

Due to non-normality and heteroscedasdicity, I use robustlmm and not lme4 for my mixed effects model. The variables look like this:

ID: subject variable (random factor)

var1: categorical between subjects variable, 2 levels

time: categorical 3 level time variable. time interval between each point is not equal therefore I cannot treat it as continuous.

cov1: continuous between subjects covariate

cov2: continuous between subjects covariate, specific to time level (cov2 is different for each subject at individual time points)

DV: continuous time-specific dependent variable, most subjects have data in every level but I also have missings

I am interested in how var1 effects DV according to different time points. Therefore my model looks like this:

rlmer(DV ~ time*var1 + cov1 + cov2 + (1|ID), data=df)

The output gives me

var1
time2
time3
cov1
cov2
time2*var1
time3*var1

I would like to get the effect of time and also the interaction term (time*var1), without dummy coding. But since R automatically converts categories into dummy variables, I cannot do it. Robustlmm does not support ANOVA calculations since there is no "likelihood-like quantity". According to my research, heteroscedastic ANCOVA is possible with wrs2 package of R but only with one covariate.

Do you have any suggestions what I can do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is the response variable, DV, strictly positive? If yes, have you considered transforming DV, eg. by taking the log or the square root?

Comment: It is strictly positive because it is based on an exponential calculation (2^x). It is very common in gene expression studies to have such variables. That is actually why I did not want to transform it since it is already a calculation.